# Apply changes to several files in the same directory

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a directory containing files with multiple extensions, though I'm only interested in working with a specific one.

- document.doc
- file_with_the.extensionwanted
- other_file.extensionwanted
- presentation.ppt
- sheet.xls
- whatever.extensionwanted

Those files I want to work with are csv-style like with the following format:

```
This is a sentence, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
This is a number: 37, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
This is a letter:  r, Info 2, Info 3,...
This is a symbol:  $, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
Here theres 'mb' too, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
```

I want to run a script that deletes every line in every file ending with .extensionwanted that contains two different strings in the 1st column, and to have the result in files with the same extension avoiding blank rows (I don't care having different names as long as they maintain the extension).

This is, for example if I want to delete lines that contain the strings '*This*' and '*mb*' in the 1st column at the same time, the wanted result would be:

```
This is a sentence, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
This is a letter:  r, Info 2, Info 3,...
Here theres 'mb' too, Info 1, Info 2, Info 3,...
```

I know how to do it with a single file with a given extension. For example, for a .csv:

```
import csv
import os

col = 0
look_for1 = set(['This'])
look_for2 = set(['mb'])

# Writing info wanted
with open('./Directory/file.csv','rb') as inf, \
        open('./Directory/other_file.csv','wb') as outf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
    outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if look_for1 in row[col] and
                                                look_for2 in[col])

os.remove('./Directory/file.csv')
```

And also how to list

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.extensionwanted")
for filename in files
    print filename
```

But in this case the extension is not .csv and I want to loop through all files in the folder with that extension.
I'm a bit lost to execute this in a dynamic environment instead of using static filenames. Could somebody give me a hand?

Comment: The output must go to an unique file or a file output for each file inputp?

Comment: "I'm a bit lost" is too vague -- what aspect of what you want to do is troubling you?

Comment: @Informatico_Sano The extension file isn't meaningful.  The important thing is its format.  A guy from Bilbao gives two kicks to the file and it's fixed it.  _Ahí va la hostia!_ ;-)

Comment: @Trimax I don't mind actually. Ideally a file for each, but all together would also be fine. The idea is to iterate donamically.

Comment: @martineau OK, to be more specific, while iterating in an environment of multiple files the sentence `outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if look_for1 not in row[col] and look_for2 not in[col] )` gives me an error that doesn't appear when I do it with a static and unique input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to select the rows you want and avoid the problem(s) you're having with the

```
outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if look_for1 in row[col] and 
                                        look_for2 in[col])
```

statement (which has multiple issues).

I've updated my answer to illustrate how to apply the filtering to multiple files in a directory using the`glob`module.

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import sys

def inplace_csv_file_filter(filepath, col, look_for):
    """ Remove rows in given csv file that contain all of the strings specified
        in look_for in the row[col] field.
    """
    backup_filepath = filepath + os.extsep + '.bak'
    try: os.unlink(backup_filepath)
    except os.error: pass
    os.rename(filepath, backup_filepath)
    with open(backup_filepath, mode='rb') as inf, open(filepath, 'wb') as outf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
        outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv
                            if not all(str_ in row[col] for str_ in look_for))
    # os.remove(backup_filepath)  # uncomment to delete backup file

col = 0
directory = './Directory'
pattern = '*.csv'
look_for = 'This', 'mb'

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, pattern)):
    inplace_csv_file_filter(filepath, col, look_for)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `os.path.splitext` function. It will allow you to extract the extension from you file, allowing you to write a filter like so:

```
extensions = set(['.csv', '.bob', '.txt'])
files = os.listdir(dirname)

target_files = [x for x in files if os.path.splitext(x)[1] in extensions]
```

You can then loop through the files in `target_files`.

Comment: well, my problem does not come with the extension (furthermore to do what you say I'd need to add a line  `if file.endswith('.wantedextension')`, as there are files of different kinds) but with the loop that writes later. I'm stuck there

Answer (score 1):

So from the code you've posted it seems that you have figured out how to **iterate filenames of specified extension** and **operate on a specific file**.  I may be oversimplying this, but can't you just smash the two together to get **operation on a iteration of files**?  It could look something like

```
import csv
import os
import glob

col = 0
look_for1 = set(['This'])
look_for2 = set(['mb'])

files = glob.glob("*.extensionwanted")
for filename in files

    #Writing info wanted
    with open(filename,'rb') as inf, open('other_'+str(filename),'wb') as outf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
        outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if look_for1 in row[col] and look_for2 in[col] )

    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: 1st of all thanks for the answer, but the code gives me an error in `outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if look_for1 in row[col] and look_for2 in[col] )`, which is what I'm trying to avoid _TypeError. 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set_
I also import the library string, btw. How could I fix this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @The2ndSon `look_for1` and `look_for2` are sets of lists, and in your expression `look_for1 in row[col] and look_for2 in[col]` you can't use the `in` operator to verify if a `set` object (or a `list` object is into a `string` Type object).

Comment: Hi @Trimax, any idea of how to solve this or to reach a solution, please?

Comment: Yes, but the solution that @martineau has given you is more elegant and I like very much.  You should accept his one and give the thank to him.  Change this lines: `look_for = ('This', 'mb')` ; `outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if not all(string_ in row[col] for string_ in look_for))`